# Performance when calling a function in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, string-formatting, plpgsql

I have a query where I need to call a SQL function to format a particular column in the query. The formatting needed is very similar to formatting a phone number, ie. changing `1234567890` into `(123)456-7890`.

I've read that calling a function from a select statement could be a performance killer, and it was kind of reflected in my situation, the time the query took more than tripled and I did not think the function would take this much longer. The function runs in linear time but does use SQL loops. To give an idea of the size of the database this particular query returns about 220,000 rows. The run time of the query went from < 3s to > 9s when running without calling the function vs. running calling the function. The column that needs formatting isn't indexed or used in a join condition or where clause.

Is the performance drop here expected or is there something I can do to improve it?

This is the function in question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn(bigint)
  RETURNS character varying LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   v_chars varchar[];
   v_ret   varchar;
   v_length int4;
   v_count  int4;
BEGIN
   if ($1 isnull or $1 = 0) then
      return null;
   end if;

   v_chars  := regexp_split_to_array($1::varchar,'');
   v_ret    := '';
   v_length := array_upper (v_chars,1);
   v_count  := 0;

   for v_index in 1..11   loop
      v_count := v_count + 1;

      if (v_index <= v_length) then
         v_ret := v_chars[v_length - (v_index - 1)] || v_ret;
      else
         v_ret := '0' || v_ret;
      end if;

      if (v_count <= 6 and (v_count % 2) = 0) then
         v_ret := '.' || v_ret;
      end if;
   end loop;

   return v_ret;
END
$BODY$
```

Comment: It's gonna depend on the query/function (we need to see them).  Usually, though, formatting is the job of your reporting program, not your database layer (you're doing it in the wrong spot).  And using loops in SQL.... is usually counter to how the language is supposed to be used.

Comment: You forgot the function header which is an integral part of the definition. Please post the complete create script. This can be improved in multiple places, but I am not going to work on a fragment.

Comment: Sorry for the late edit I had no access to the code since I got off work, I added the header.

Comment: A comment only reaches me if you properly [@reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Found it by chance, revisiting the question on a hunch. Also found a radical solution (I think). Your function is still imcomplete, though. Had to fix it up to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specifics of the function. To find out how much a *bare function call* will cost, create dummy functions like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_bare_plpgsql(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN $1;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE FUNCTION f_bare_sql(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$BODY$
   SELECT $1;
$BODY$;
```

And try your query again.
If then you wonder why your function is slow, add it to your question.

---

#### Solution for updated question

Your function could be improved in many places, but there is a more radical solution:

```
SELECT to_char(12345678901, '00000"."00"."00"."00')
```

Many times faster, obviously. More about [`to_char()` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).
Consider the following demo:

```
WITH x(n) AS (
   VALUES  (1::bigint), (12), (123), (1234), (12345), (123456), (1234567)
          ,(12345678), (123456789), (1234567890), (12345678901), (123456789012)
   )
SELECT n, x.fn(n), to_char(n, '00000"."00"."00"."00')
FROM x

      n       |       fn       |     to_char
--------------+----------------+-----------------
            1 | 00000.00.00.01 |  00000.00.00.01
           12 | 00000.00.00.12 |  00000.00.00.12
          123 | 00000.00.01.23 |  00000.00.01.23
         1234 | 00000.00.12.34 |  00000.00.12.34
        12345 | 00000.01.23.45 |  00000.01.23.45
       123456 | 00000.12.34.56 |  00000.12.34.56
      1234567 | 00001.23.45.67 |  00001.23.45.67
     12345678 | 00012.34.56.78 |  00012.34.56.78
    123456789 | 00123.45.67.89 |  00123.45.67.89
   1234567890 | 01234.56.78.90 |  01234.56.78.90
  12345678901 | 12345.67.89.01 |  12345.67.89.01
 123456789012 | 23456.78.90.12 |  #####.##.##.##
```

`to_char()` is only prepared for up to 11 decimal digits, as you can see.
Can easily be extended, if need should be.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I tried it with the dummy function and the running time pretty much did not go up at all compared to just returning the column. I thought the function was slower than expected because the function itself doesn't do anything crazy, it's a simple loop. I am new at this, however, so maybe my common sense on how fast things should run is terribly wrong when it's run on a big database.

Comment: I decided to take your advice and try to avoid adding a column, I changed your testing method a little bit and found something interesting. The function in question uses the postgres function regexp_split_to_array, what I did was I modified the dummy functions you gave me, made it so that they make a call to regexp_split_to_array and doing nothing else before returning. There was then a noticeable difference between doing select f_bare_plpgsql(a),... and select regexp_split_to_array(a),... I imagine this difference will only grow bigger, why do you supposed this is?

Comment: @LinDu: `regexp_split_to_array()` can be slow, depending on the the regexp you use. Replace with `string_to_array()` if you can ...

Comment: Thank you for a very elegant and efficient solution! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really *must* perform the formatting in the database then modify your table to include a field to store the formatted number.

A trigger can call your function to generate the formatted number when the value changes, then you only (slightly) increase the time taken to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a few rows at a time, rather than all of them.

Your query returning all 220k rows then becomes a simple `SELECT` of the formatted value and should be nice and quick.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! I think I will give this a try, hopefully they won't mind me adding a column to the table.

Comment: @LinDu: I would advise against adding columns with redundant data. It will slow down *every* other operation because of the unnecessary table bloat and should only be an option for expensive calculations. A simple formatting function like you describe should be *very* fast. Just fix it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I agree with what you say, the function should be able to execute fast enough, I just wanted to put forward an alternative solution. And yes, the formatted values should not really be stored in the same table if it will impact other operations significantly. In which case use a separate table for them and join to it when required.